# How to use configuration file from ~/.aws/config instead of shared-credentials-file location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config, aws-credentials

When I list the credentials this is the output:

```
aws configure list



Name                    Value             Type    Location
----                    -----             ----    --------
profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************ABCD  shared-credentials-file     
secret_key     ****************ABCD  shared-credentials-file    
region                us-west-2             env    ~/.aws/config
```

But I require to use the credential file from ~/.aws/ insted of shared-credetials-file

```
access_key     ****************ABCD      config_file    ~/.aws/config
secret_key     ****************ABCD      config_file    ~/.aws/config
```

I tried to use these commands but is not working.

```
setx AWS_CONFIG_FILE c:\some\file\path\on\the\system\config-file-name
setx AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE C:\Users\username\.aws\credentials
```

Is possible to reset in order to use the credentials from .aws folder?